# How can i query a array of model classes inside a document

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I have a RecyclerView in my Android app and I have a FirestoreRecyclerAdapter that takes a model class (class name = Chat.kt)

Now in my Firestore, I have a document that holds an ArrayList of  the above-said class.

I want to query and get that ArrayList of .

[Firestore Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTJBw.png)

So basically I want that chat array to act as a collection and all the models inside that array as a document hope you understood.

[can you suggest me a query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgsen.png)

Answer (score 0):

> So basically I want that chat array to act as a collection.

That's simply not possible. FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder's [setQuery()](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/3d578ef2ef110ca01e07ba64f1a0808fcd279e4c/firestore/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/firestore/FirestoreRecyclerOptions.java#L85) method, requires a Firestore Query as an argument. This means that the FirestoreRecyclerAdapter will render a view for each and every document that will be present in the result set. So there is no way you can pass a list of custom objects instead of a Query and act in the same way. What you can so, is to read the content of your `chat` array, and map each object into an object of your "Chat" class, as I have explained in one of my articles:

- [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10)

You'll lose the benefits of the Firebase-UI library but it will do the trick. So, unfortunately, you can't mix them together, it's one or the other.